# ASP.NET: UpdatePanel & OnLoad Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, onload

I'm trying to execute some javascript code on my UpdatePanel's OnLoad event like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updDropDowns" runat="server" OnLoad="javascript:ResetButtons();">
```

But I keep getting "'javascript' is not a member of ASP.reasons_aspx".

I tried doing

```
Me.updDropDowns.Attributes.Add("OnLoad", "javascript:ResetButtons();")
```

But I can't reference the 'Attributes' property of an UpdatePanel in the VB code-behind.

How else can I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: What about removing `javascript:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to register a clientscript:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pagestart", "ResetButtons();", true)
```

**edit:** Updated per Tim's note.  I referenced the wrong class

Comment: In an Async Postback? @Jason should use the [ScriptManagers's RegisterStartupScript method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx) instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 'registerstartupscript' just puts your code inside a pair of script tags.  It's not doing anything like putting it in a $(document).ready() jQuery event.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, their is no client OnLoad event for an updatepanel (it's rendered as a div or a span). It's only server side. And dont forget, the event will be fired each and every time the panel gets updated. Why dont you just reset your buttons server side ?

Comment: Problem with that is if I disable the buttons server-side, they're a bit difficult to reference later on in the client. I ended up doing something similar to David's idea. But thanks for your post!